# CPT Post Title Permalink: Replace "@" (or all special characters) with dash "-" instead of just removing

Tags: permalinks, title, characters

I have Custom Post Type "Email", where the Post Title is always going to be an email address, ie: **example@domain.com**

The problem I am having is the "@" is being removed in the permalink: **../exampledomain-com**

I would like it to save as: **../example-domain-com**

Replacing the "@" with a "-"

I tried the following [from here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/sanitize_title), but as someone more knowledgeable will quickly see, it doesn't apply to the permalink:

```
function at_to_dash($title) {
    return str_replace('@', '-', $title);
}
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'at_to_dash');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure your filter runs *before* the one that Wordpress itself applies - add a priority of 9:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', function( $title ) {

    if ( FALSE !== strpos( $title, '@' ) ) {
        $title = str_replace( '@', '-', $title );
    }

    return $title;

}, 9 );
```

Usage:

```
echo sanitize_title( 'mytitle@example.org' );
```

Output:

```
mytitle-example-org
```

Comment: Well, well, well. Thank you. It works! I wasn't sure if I was on the right track. Accepted answer.